# Hide notch on Android 11

Tags: adb, screen, android-11, fairphone-4

I just got my Fairphone 4, and, overall the device is nice, but I can't get used to the notch.

Since the display aspect ratio is super tall anyways and I can use a bit more bezel on the bottom as well (for a keyboard attachment that I built and used on my last phone), I figured, I'd use `wm size` over adb to just reduce the screen's vertical resolution and thus create bezels on top and bottom.

But after I did that, this is what happened:

[image: screenshot]

Sorry for the bad picture quality.

What happened is, it didn't remove the rounded corners and/or the notch, it just moved them farther down. So apparently, the OS doesn't seem to render the pixels behind the screen cutouts at all, and when I made the used screen area smaller, it just moved those dead zones with it. Even if I shrink the vertical resolution to 1000 pixel (which is less than half), the behaviour stays the same.

Is there a way to disable that functionality?

I want to end up with just a square display area.

It would be best if I can get that only with adb/onboard stuff. If you are recommending an app for that, it should be one that doesn't have ads/microtransactions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accidentally, I had a similar problem myself recently. I believe I see USB debugging is enabled on your phone. Go into developer options and scroll 3/4 of the way down to the *Drawing* section. In there you have a setting called *Display cutout*. Change that to *hide*.

Alternatively, you can root your phone and install Magisk. Inside Magisk you can install a module called *None Display Cutout* by MlgmXyysd. After installing, go to the same setting under developer options and select *No display cutout*. This module let's your phone think it doesn't even have a notch. You can play around with this but probably the first option will work best for you.

Comment: Nice, thanks, I will try it out! Hope it works here, because the Display cutout setting doesn't have the "hide" option at all on my phone...

Comment: The Magisk route worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: No worries, happy to help :)

Comment: You can always use cmd overlay list in adb shell to see RROs and disable the cutout one.

Comment: Ah, thanks, that would have been easier indeed.